# Google Cloud Build Timed out 10 min

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-build

I try to create a deployment in GKE from BitBucket repository with "*New container image*" option.

[Create a deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bleN.png)
[Building a container image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaQGz.png)

But I receive ***ERROR: Timed out*** when my container is building.

[Execution details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX2l0.png)
[Timed out error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbUM5.png)

Additionaly I tryed to set params, but it did not help:

```
gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1600
gcloud config set builds/timeout 1600
gcloud config set container/build_timeout 1600
```

How can I change the limit in Cloud Build ws GKE if I don't have access to **cloudbuild.yaml** config file with GKE Workloads pipeline?

Comment: For the non GKE, check out this other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727071/google-cloud-build-timing-out

Answer (score 0):

Built in feature use default parameters that you can't override.

If you have a too long container to build, trigger a Cloud Build to build your container separately, with the appropriate timeout, and then deploy this container on GKE.

Industrial solution build and deploy in the same time, in the same Cloud Build.